# How to parse function in Object at JSON in node js

Tags: javascript, parsing

Hi I'm trying to parse data, i used JSON.parse(), data.items.reqHandler is a function, but JSON.parse recognize reqHandler to string. In this case, how can i get data change to js not to use JSON.parse(JSON.parse(....)) ?

```
data.json = {
    items: [
        {
            ID: "11",
            reqHandler: function requestHandler(ex) {
                return {
                ...
                };
            };
            },
            ...
        }
    ],
    count: 0,
    action: "batchprocess",
    headers: {
    ...
    },
    stage: "dev"
};
```

Comment: Try `data.json.items[0].reqHandler`

Comment: Do you want to invoke your request handler on the server side or just want to use it on successful response?

Comment: @Tân in console.log(data.json.items[0].reqHandler), it returns looks like function, but console.log(type of data.json.items[0].reqHandler) = string. I want to use data.json.items[0].reqHandler(ex) , but it doesn't move.

Comment: @MaddyBlacklisted yes i want to invoke requestHandler

Comment: I think it could be better to get help if you provide the response string and the way to parse it. You can edit your question and add more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function is defined somewhere, You can try

```
let fn = window['requestHandler'];
if(typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn(ex);
}
```

In this particular case, function `requestHandler` is defined. `const fn = window["requestHandler"]` would obtain a reference to function requestHandler (ex) {}. Once we have a reference to a function inside a variable, we can call this function by "calling the variable", i.e. `fn(ex)`, which equals `requestHandler(ex)`, which is what the OP wants.